# Route is retaining old route prop values after clicking Link to a New Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router `^5.2.0`

I have my router setup as so for the route in question:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        path="/companies/:companyId/details"
        render={(props: RouteComponentProps<{ companyId: string }>) => (
            <CompanyDetailContainer
                {...props} //  pass routing props
                fetchCompanyNew={fetchCompanyNew}
                findOne={findOne}
                httpRequest={Request}
                useFetchDataCompany={useFetchDataCompany}
            />
        )}
    />
    <Route component={withTracker(Container)} path="/" />
    <Route component={withTracker(NotFound)} path="*" />
</Switch>
```

Here's what a Company Link looks like that I'm clicking on

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const uri = company.notInterviewed ? `companies/${company.id}/details` : `/interviews/companies/${company.id}`

<Link className={className} id={company.id.toString()} to={uri}>
  <span id="company-name">{company.name}</span>
</Link>
```

**The problem:** When I click back using the browser, then click on another company, the ID is still set to the previous route's company ID even though I clicked to route to another companyId.

**For example:**

1. I click on a company link from the homepage to navigate to `/companies/10/details`
2. I click BACK in my browser to navigate back to the main homepage that has a list of company links
3. I click on a different company link from the homepage to navigate to `/companies/20/details`

the problem is even though the url has an ID of `20` in it after the second click, the ID I'm getting from react-router props a companyId of `10`